# Is this external hard-drive failing? (clicking noise, not recognized on Windows)

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

My uncle gave me a hard-drive to troubleshoot. When I plug it to the power and USB the hard-drive does a clicky sound ([video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13m9XiIFCV7bddJNRAQvWdf1AJxHTTQhG/view)) which sounds kinda weird but it's already a sign of failing. If I incline the disk it stops but this disk can't be detected in Disk Management as well.

This disk is already dead?

Comment: Either drive is bad or the controller in the hard drive case, remove it from the hard drive case and connect it using the proper hard drive usb adapter cable. The drive itself may be good. I just did this for an old Seagate 750gb drive enclosure I had, pulled the clicking drive from the case and it worked via a new adapter, still using it.

Comment: @Moab thanks for tip, my first thought was pulling out of the case but I don't really have a sata-usb adapter right now.

Comment: Its your best bet to see if it is good and still usable.

Comment: That looks like a pretty old drive.  There's a good chance it's IDE.

Comment: I'll pop it out today to check this

Comment: @Moab thanks, I confirmed that the case itself was the trouble (tried to connect a spare drive to it). I don't really have a SATA-USB adapter to test if it's alright but definitely helped me.